# How to output a hyperlink in an ejs template

Tags: ejs

I have an email template written as an ejs file. It's completely text with some dynamic variables rendered using ejs. There is no HTML tags as of now.
I want to insert a hyperlink to the email but it's not working

I tried adding the link like `<a href=#> here </a>` , for example.
But instead of outputting **here** I'm getting the entire thing  *here*  as it is.
What am I missing. How can I get this to output a link like it should be.